# Merge logs between date/time using filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I'm trying to push logs to `elasticSearch` using `fileBeat` ( No Logstash )

I want to send following log in single message but it get broken into multiple messages, every line becomes separate message

```
20161014 17:49:09.169 [ERROR] [Thread-2974] some.java.class.:70 - some.java.Exception: write failed. History: [requestHost=123-some.org.com, time=Fri Oct 14 17:49:05 GMT-07:00 2016, exception=java.net.SocketTimeoutException]
[requestHost=123-some.org.com, time=Fri Oct 14 17:49:07 GMT-07:00 2016, exception=java.net.SocketTimeoutException]
[requestHost=123-some.org.com, time=Fri Oct 14 17:49:09 GMT-07:00 2016, exception=java.net.SocketTimeoutException]
 Tried 3 times
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20161014 17:49:09.169 [ERROR] [Thread-3022]
```

I want to merge all lines between 2 dates (1st and last line)

Here is my `filebeat.yml` snippet

```
 paths:
      - /test.log
      multiline.pattern: '^\[0-9]{8}'
      multiline.negate: true
      multiline.match: after
```

I need to know correct `regex`

I'm trying to solve this without using `logstash`

Comment: By escaping the open bracket, you're removing its power and matching on the literal bracket.

Comment: I tried some regex on go playground ( from filebeat documentation) they are work but in practice all of them are giving me same problem, i am not a regex ninja yet looks like i need to spend some time and nail this or just use logstash with GROK filter

Comment: The dotted config provided in this question worked for me. Filebeat version - 6.8.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following Filebeat configuration with the provided log sample produces two events where each message begins with the date.

I ran `./filebeat -c filebeat.yml -e -v -d "*"` with the config below to test. I also tested the pattern on the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wzbqs9CzKc).

filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - paths: ["input.txt"]
      multiline:
        pattern: '^[0-9]{8}'
        negate:  true
        match:   after
output:
  console:
    pretty: false
```

Output:

```
{   
  "@timestamp": "2016-10-17T14:13:31.292Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "host.example.com",
    "name": "host.example.com",
  },  
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": "20161014 17:49:09.169 [ERROR] [Thread-2974] some.java.class.:70 - some.java.Exception: write failed. History: [requestHost=123-some.org.com, time=Fri Oct 14 17:49:05 GMT-07:00 2016, exception=java.net.SocketTimeoutException]\n[requestHost=123-some.org.com, time=Fri Oct 14 17:49:07 GMT-07:00 2016, exception=java.net.SocketTimeoutException]\n[requestHost=123-some.org.com, time=Fri Oct 14 17:49:09 GMT-07:00 2016, exception=java.net.SocketTimeoutException]\n Tried 3 times\n        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)",
  "offset": 519,
  "source": "input.txt",
  "type": "log"
}   
{   
  "@timestamp": "2016-10-17T14:17:21.686Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "host.example.com",
    "name": "host.example.com",
  },  
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": "20161014 17:49:09.169 [ERROR] [Thread-3022]",
  "offset": 563,
  "source": "input.txt",
  "type": "log"
}
```

Comment: I dont see "\n" and messages are still broken into pieces, these are log4j logs do you think it makes any difference ?

Comment: What version of Filebeat are you running? What OS? I tried this on the 5.0-rc1 on OS X and it worked fine. I don't think the fact that they are log4j logs makes any difference.

Comment: I am using `filebeat version 1.3.1 (amd64)` on ubuntu 14.04.03.   If i can find/write a regex which starts `^[0-9]{8}` and end at next occurrence of same `^[0-9]{8}` do you think that can solve my problem ?

Comment: I tested the config I provided on 1.3.1 and it works with the log sample you gave. BTW the config you posted in your question is not valid for 1.3.1 since the indentation is wrong and you cannot use dotted keys like `multiline.pattern`. Please try the exact config and commands given in my answer. If they don't work then can you provide a larger log sample with examples of how the lines are to be grouped into events.

Comment: Thanks a ton for persistently trying to resolve my issue, Everything fall in place after getting rid of dotted keys